# showInputMethodPicker not working on devices above Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-input-method, inputmethodmanager

In the documentation, I saw that

`showInputMethodPicker`
Added in API level 3
public void showInputMethodPicker ()
Show IME picker popup window.

> Requires the PackageManager#FEATURE_INPUT_METHODS feature which can be detected using PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(String).

I don't know how to add `FEATURE_INPUT_METHODS to enable the choose keyboard popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System features are set by device manufacturers, based on the device capabilities. An app does not add them.

The statement in the documentation about `FEATURE_INPUT_METHODS` is so that you can detect if the device that your app runs on supports input methods, so you know whether it makes sense to call `showInputMethodPicker()` or not.